# Python REST call to VB

Tags: python, vb6

First - I admit I'm in over my head on this.  I know how do do SOAP calls, but this REST stuff is all new to me.

I have a Python script that calls our company CRM and it's working as it should.  I need to convert this over to VB6 (or even VB .net), but I can't seem to figure out just how to get the thing to work.  I know I'm talking to the CRM, but it keeps giving me an error (probably because I'm sending wrong data).

Here's the working Python Script (NOTE: the authtoken variable comes from another script that's working fine):

```
fetchurl = https://URL-TO-THE-REST-FUNCTION

searchheaders = {
    'accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authtoken
    }

payloadstring = {
    "request": {
        "companyNumber": 1,
        "operatorInit": "user",
        "operatorPassword": "Password",
        "inputString": "TEST_STRING"
    }
}

payload = json.dumps(payloadstring)

fetchresponse = requests.post(fetchurl,
    headers=searchheaders,
    data=payload,
    verify=False)

apiResponse = fetchresponse.content

print(json.loads(apiResponse))
```

And here's what I have so far in VB6

```
Dim sURL As String
Dim strXML As String
Dim xmlhttp As MSXML2.xmlhttp

Set xmlhttp = New xmlhttp

Open "D:\API\token.dat" For Input As #1
Line Input #1, token$
Close #1

Data$ = "'{" & Chr$(34) & "request" & Chr$(34) & ": {"
Data$ = Data$ & Chr$(34) & "companyNumber" & Chr$(34) & ": 1,"
Data$ = Data$ & Chr$(34) & "operatorInit" & Chr$(34) & ": " & Chr$(34) & "user" &     Chr$(34) & ","
Data$ = Data$ & Chr$(34) & "operatorPassword" & Chr$(34) & ": " & Chr$(34) & "password" & Chr$(34) & ","
Data$ = Data$ & Chr$(34) & "inputString" & Chr$(34) & ": " & Chr$(34) & "Work, Damnit!" & Chr$(34) & "}}'"

sURL = "https://URL-TO-The-REST-FUNCTION"
strXML = Data$

xmlhttp.open "POST", sURL, True
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "'accept':", "'application/json; charset=utf-8'"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "'Content-Type':", "'application/json;charset=utf-8'"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "'Authorization': 'Barer '", token$ & "'"
xmlhttp.send strXML
```

The Data$ looks like this:

```
'{"request": {"companyNumber": 1,"operatorInit": "user","operatorPassword": "password","inputString": "Work, Damnit!"}}'
```

I know I'm at least talking to the server, the returned header looks like this:

```
Date: Fri, 04 Mar 2022 20:28:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 24
Connection: keep-alive
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-transaction-id: 5dfcb31d-9d85-94ce-b6cd-81416aaab4c2
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
www-authenticate: Bearer realm="IONAPI"
server: ionapi-2022.02.00.995424
x-envoy-decorator-operation: ionapi_gateway
```

And the response I'm getting is

```
{"error":"Unauthorized"}
```

(I know the username/password I'm plugging in are good)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your header field Authorization has `Barer`, should be `Bearer`, unless that's just a typo in the posted code. Also I don't think all the single quotes should be there?

Comment: I fixed the "Bearer" typo and removed the single quotes from the code - no go.

Comment: Use a proxy tool like Fiddler to capture the raw HTTP request from both Python and VB6, your problem will be whatever the difference between is.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear those headers for you

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Barer " & token$
```

There is no `'` in the header name, there is no `:` in the header name, there is no `'` in the header value too.

The `Authorization` value is `Bearer {token_here}`, so `Bearer` is not part of the header name but the header value.

There is no need to specify `charset` for `application/json` content-type as this is always in utf-8 and no other charset is supported by definition (this is not XML where you can have various charsets).

JFYI, header `Content-Type` means your `strXML` contains JSON i.e. this is the content of the body you are posting.

Header `Accept` means you expect JSON from the server to be returned. Try omitting this for brevity if your endpoint defaults to JSON output.